# ansible yum check update parse output to have list of packages

Tags: linux, ansible, yum

I want to parse the output of yum check-update ansible equivalent to get only the list of package in human readable format.

My code so far:

```
- name: check for updates
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

 - name: check for updates (yum)
   yum: list=updates update_cache=true
   register: yumoutput
   when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
 - debug: msg={{ yumoutput.stdout | from_json }}
```

but I get:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ yumoutput.stdout | from_json }}): expected string or buffer"}

EDIT: the complete playbook:

```
---
- name: check for updates
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - name: check for updates (yum)
    yum: list=updates update_cache=true
    register: yumoutput
    when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
  - debug: var=yumoutput
    msg: "{{ yumoutput.results | map(attribute='name') | list }}
```

Answer (score 5):

`yum` module does not register `stdout` key ― you can see it using `debug: var=yumoutput`.

You need to extract the package names from the list of dictionaries, for example:

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ yumoutput.results | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

Comment: the "debug:var" is nice to understand but with you debug example i have:

    [WARNING]: Ignoring invalid attribute: msg

Comment: Most likely because you did not keep the correct indentation.

Comment: i update the original question with the complete playbook

Answer (score 2):

Some minor syntax errors in the complete playbook. This did it for me

```
 ---
    - name: check for updates
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: true
    
      tasks:
          - name: check for updates (yum)
            yum: list=updates update_cache=true
            register: yumoutput
            when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
          - debug:
              msg: "{{ yumoutput.results | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the above-mentioned solution. You can use call back plugin for ease of reading the output.

Below is one of the human-readable call-back plugin:

```
https://github.com/n0ts/ansible-human_log
```

More info about call back plugins:

```
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/callback.html
```